# ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded,coursed by blob.getBinaryStream();

Tags: java, oracle

I query datas from database,then convert blob data to string,but has an exception happened:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

```
ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.v8TTILob.receiveReply(v8TTILob.java:991)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.v8TTILob.getChunkSize(v8TTILob.java:347)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.getLobChunkSize(TTC7Protocol.java:3091)
    at oracle.sql.LobDBAccessImpl.getChunkSize(LobDBAccessImpl.java:334)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getChunkSize(BLOB.java:484)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBufferSize(BLOB.java:521)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:256)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Blob_oracle_sql_BLOB.getBinaryStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.creationstar.bjtax.qsgl.BizLogic.dao.clfgl.FwxxDAO.convertBlobToString(FwxxDAO.java:138)
    at com.creationstar.bjtax.qsgl.BizLogic.dao.clfgl.FwxxDAO.queryFwList(FwxxDAO.java:379)
    at com.creationstar.bjtax.qsgl.BizLogic.processor.clfgl.ClfxxcjProcessor.getCjxx(ClfxxcjProcessor.java:473)
    at com.creationstar.bjtax.qsgl.BizLogic.processor.clfgl.ClfjyxxCXProcessor.doQuery(ClfjyxxCXProcessor.java:173)
    at com.creationstar.bjtax.qsgl.BizLogic.processor.clfgl.ClfjyxxCXProcessor.process(ClfjyxxCXProcessor.java:50)
```

the code is this:

```
public ArrayList queryFwList(String conditions)
        throws SQLException {
    ArrayList fwxxList = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "select  sbbh,htbh,fwcqzh,fwsyqztfrq,fwzlqx,fwzldz,fwjzmj,jzjgdm,ghyt,fwqszylx,zcs,szlc,htwsqyrq,sfwscsssggf,htzj,bzdm,bzmc,hl,wbje,fdczjjgmc,bbbs,swjgzzjgdm,sfesf,cjr,cjrq,lrr,lrrq,bz,ewmsj,FWXZDM,xxly from qsdb.qs_jl_fwxxb "
            + conditions;

    Debug.out("queryFwList:" + sql);                
    Connection conn=null;       
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {

        try {
            conn = QSDBUtil.getConnection();
        } catch (BaseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                   

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Fwxx fwxx = new Fwxx();

            fwxx.setSbbh(rs.getString("sbbh"));
                               ...
                               ...
            if (rs.getBlob("ewmsj") != null
                    && !"".equals(rs.getBlob("ewmsj"))) {
                fwxx.setEwmsj(convertBlobToString(rs.getBlob("ewmsj")));
            }

            fwxx.setFwxzdm(rs.getString("FWXZDM"));
            fwxx.setXxly(rs.getString("xxly"));

            fwxxList.add(fwxx);
        }
        System.out.println(" FwxxList size:" + fwxxList.size());
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        ps.close();
        QSDBUtil.freeConnection(conn);
    }
    return fwxxList;
}
```

//the code  to convert Blob to string.

```
public String convertBlobToString(Blob blob) {

        String result = "";
        try {
            InputStream inStream = (InputStream) blob.getBinaryStream();
            if (blob != null)   
            try {
                byte[] data = new byte[200];
                int length = 0;
                while ((length = inStream.read(data, 0, 200)) != -1) {
                    String str = new String(data, 0, length);
                    result = result + str;
                }
                inStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please add code with creating/closing jdbc statement.

Comment: Seems, you do not close cursors somewhere in the program when you are done with them.

Comment: "*maximum open cursors exceeded*" almost always indicates a bug in your program. You are not closing your `ResultSet`s and `Statement`s properly

Comment: As a complement to the other comments, I notice that you close you stream in the `try` block. This is a bad habit as in case of exception the resource is *not* closed. You should always close in the `finally` block -- or using a [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Probably there is a similar issue elsewhere in your program preventing a proper closing of your cursors...